# startActivityForResult() alternative for fragment( getting task done by fragment and passing result to fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, bundle, fragmenttransaction

```
              >>activity B   |   activity B >> activity A
activity A >>                |
              >>activity C   |   activity C >> activity A
```

Activity A showing a viewpager which is scrolling through an arraylist of applicants

In Activity A we can click on a button and go to activity B or C activity B and C are doing task such as shortlisting or scheduling interview of an applicant after that it will come to activity A with some data in intent.

So B and C are called through startActivityForResult method, and returning the result along with an intent after doing the task.

My question is,
 i am converting these activities to fragments(because i need to implement bottom navigation bar so wrapping these flow under a single menu) the first part, creating viewpager, going to each fragments are done now,
so it is now

Fragment A(viewpager), Fragment B(shortlist), Fragment C(schedule interview)

but if i have to return from the shortlist or schedule-interview fragment with the "result bundle" what should i do? simply ".replace()" the fragment with the viewpager fragment along with bundle without adding to backstack? i have cancel buttons in B and C(shortlist and scheduleinterview fragments) and i am implementing this cancel button with ".remove()" for fragment now, am i doing it correctly? or is there any workaround for this? and can we send a bundle to the calling fragment before the ".remove()" is happening? (can we remove shortlist or scheduleinterview fragment and send the data to the calling fragment ?)

I need to do this with fragments because I need to implement this within a bottom navigation bar